# Simple primitive rotation Opengl c

Tags: c, opengl

Im trying to do a simple rotation in opengl of my primitive object in the projection plane. I want to rotate the object like a propeller but i cant seem to get it going right. When i run the code my object looks like it shrinks into itself (i know its not that, but its rotating funny)

```
    void rotateStuff() 
    {
      spin = spin - .5; // inc for spin
      if(spin < 360)
      {
         spin = spin + 360;
      }
      glPushMatrix();
          glTranslatef(150, 95, 0.0);
          glRotatef(spin, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
          glTranslatef(-150, -95, 0);
          displayStuff();
      glPopMatrix();

      drawButton();
      glutSwapBuffers();
   }
```

Heres a snippet of my object

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2i(50, 0);
    glVertex2i(50, 75);

    glVertex2i(150, 75);
    glVertex2i(150, 0);

glEnd(); // end current shape
```

I think something is wrong with the setting of my origin but what exaclty? am i translating to a wrong origin?

Comment: Don't mix rendering with state updates. You should do `rotateStuff(); drawStuff();`.

Comment: im not quite sure what u mean, are you saying i should call displayStuff() outside of rotateStuff()?

Comment: Yes, things get much easier if you separate the updating of your "world" from rendering it. (You're not noticing yet because your program is small, but you will...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rotation around the x-axis: `glRotatef(spin, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)`.

Presumably you want things in the x-y plane to stay in the x-y plane,
so you want rotation around the z-axis: `glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: To spin around a point isnt quite what i was looking for which was to rotate around its center. To get it to spin around its center, i divided the x & y positions by 2 in each glTranslate . i.e. glTranslatef(150/2, 95/2, 0.0); is this really a way of precisely rotating around a primitives center?

Comment: I figured you would also need to adjust your glTranslate functions but that you would know how to do that (as you evidently do) once the direction of the axis of rotation was OK.